# how to use php built in server as a deamon

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm using php 5.4.7 and in my every development day basis i have to run php built in server like 100 times a day most times for the same project i want to know is there any way to write a php program that runs as a deamon on gnu-linux-ubuntu.13.04 and writes log information to a certain file.

I want to just once run this command:

```
php myserver.php --host="localhost" --port="8000"
```

then close the terminal and have the server up for the rest of the day.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you need if often, consider `supervisord`. Easy starting & stopping, automatic restarting on failure, etc.

Comment: sound similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464295/how-can-i-test-perfornamce-of-php-project-using-apache-benchmark

Comment: @codepiper it seems that question is about benchmarking with apache.

Comment: If you just want to close the terminal and leave it running, you could use `nohup` to invoke the command.

Comment: Why not just use apache? Seems like it would make things easier than trying to reinvent a web server using the php built-in web server.